# Why is object.constructor a "Function", and not "newable" in TypeScript?

Tags: types, constructor, typescript

In TypeScript, I usually define the type of a class type with:

```
declare type Type = { 
    new (...args: any[]): any
}
```

For example, this can used when a class is passed as an argument. This is kind-of similar to what `Type` is in C#, but it can also be instantiated directly with the `new` operator. AFAIK, this type definition is effectively analogous to:

> A constructor function that may receive any number and type of arguments, and may return anything.

If an argument, property, or other variable is expected to contain a reference to a class (more precisely, to its constructor function), the `Type` type is always at hand, and is very useful to me.

---

However, sometimes I come across situations where I don't have a reference to the class (constructor function) itself, only its prototype. However, it's still possible to get a reference to the class itself by

```
obj.constructor
```

Which is of type `Function` however, and is not possible to instantiate as a class:

```
new obj.constructor(); // Error: Cannot use 'new' ...
```

This yields the error:

> Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature.

If I use type assertions, the compiler accepts the `new` operator, and the compiled code behaves as expected at runtime.

**Is there something I'm missing which explains why `obj.constructor` is not newable off-the-shelf?**

Comment: could you give as a complete example of the code? I tried to reproduce what you have and it's pretty obvious why you couldn't call **new obj.constructor()** from the generated js. There is no **constructor** property on the a object. http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=type%20Type%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20new%20(...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%3A%20any%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20a%3A%20Type%20%3D%20class%20A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20b%20%3D%20new%20a()%3B

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because TypeScript currently has no special handling for the `constructor` property. It's [defined in lib.d.ts for the Object interface,](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/release-1.8/lib/lib.d.ts#L96) so it can only be generically defined as a Function.

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3841 and https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4356 are the relevant issues.

You can do this:

```
class Foo {
    constructor(public x: string) { }
}
var foo = new Foo("foo");

var bar = new (foo.constructor as { new(x: string): typeof foo })("bar");
```

which allows you to be generic on the type of `foo` (i.e. you don't need to explicitly write `Foo` in the type assertion), but you still need to write the parameters explicitly or cop out with `...args: any[]`.