# Create a new instance using the type of a parameter in generic function

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I implemented a generic function to merge options with default options:

```
  // definition
  protected defaultOptions<T>(options: T, type: new () => T): T {
    return {
      ...options,
      ...new type(),
    };
  }
```

It works like a charm but I always need to pass the type as second parameter:

```
  // use it like this
  upload(file: File, options: FilesUploadOptions) {
    options = this.defaultOptions(options, FilesUploadOptions);
    ...
    ...
  }
```

Question:

There is a way to achieve the same result, but removing the second parameter of the method defaultOptions and get and create new instance with the type from the first parameter?

```
  // definition
  protected defaultOptions<T>(options: T): T {

    const type = ???????; // some smart type generics here :)

    return {
      ...options,
      ...new type(),
    };
  }
```

In this way I could use it simply like this:

```
  upload(file: File, options: FilesUploadOptions) {
    options = this.defaultOptions(options);
    ...
    ...
  }
```

Thanks!

Comment: TypeScript compiles to JavaScript, which is what actually runs.  How would you imagine this working in JavaScript?  You could possibly do something like `new options.constructor()`, assuming the `options` parameter was itself a class instance of a zero-arg constructor, but TypeScript won't be able to verify that this will work.

Comment: Here is a relevant question that address why typescript is unable to verify such things: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36138095/why-is-object-constructor-a-function-and-not-newable-in-typescript. Basically, the type of `constructor` is simply `Function`, but the `constructor` function has special behavior in javascript (it is newable). This is still the case, even with the newest version of typescript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There is a way to achieve the same result, but removing the second parameter of the method defaultOptions and get and create new instance with the type from the first parameter?

No that's not possible. In TypeScript, types are a purely compile time construct. When compiling to JavaScript they are removed. This means there's no way to access them during runtime.