# TypeScript - Create an instance using the constructor property

Tags: javascript, typescript, constructor, instance, instanceof

I want to create a function called `createInstance` that receives an instance `a` and creates a new instance `c` that is of the same type as `a`. Note that inside of `createInstance` I do not know what is the type of `a`, I only know it inherits from some class `A`. But I want `c` to be of type `B`, which is the real type of `a`. This is what I've got so far:

```
class A {
    constructor(public ref: string) {}
}

class B extends A {
}

const createInstance = (a: A): void => {
    const t = a.constructor
    const c = new t("c")
    console.log(c)
    console.log(c instanceof B)
}

const b = new B("b")
createInstance(b)
```

I've tried it in the typescript playground and it works, I get `true` for `c instanceof B`. But it shows a warning in the `new t("c")` line, that says: "This expression is not constructable. Type 'Function' has no construct signatures."

What is the correct way to do this? Thanks

Comment: You want to do this...why? How is it supposed to know what arguments to pass to the constructor? If you have A in scope to type the argument, why not just call new A directly? This doesn't really make any sense.

Comment: @JaredSmith The code I shared is a minimal example of the problem. It does not illustrate the usage. I have `A` in scope but I don't want `c` to just be of type `A`, I want it to be of the same type as `b`. In this case, `B`. But I can't know inside of `createInstance` which type of instance to create, I just know it should be a subclass of `A` and the same type as `a`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This actually is still a missing feature in TypeScript, since `T.constructor` is not of type T but just a plain function. You can force-cast it:

```
const t = a.constructor as { new(ref: string): A };
```

Edit: you can have the constructor already typed (parameters list) using `ConstructorParameters`:

```
const t = a.constructor as { new(...args: ConstructorParameters<typeof A>): A };
```

See a relative issue on TS repository[#4536](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4356) and this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36138095/why-is-object-constructor-a-function-and-not-newable-in-typescript)

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8BQ1XWAewHYQC4CcBXYXDfACgAdCAjEAS2GnwFMAzALmj33qwHMAlIgC+SMUlCQYAIWgsAHrhZYAJjHjIJmHLnSswygJK6wWYC2gBeaOTBdYgrgDcM9VdYB8iFGh15oPRswADp-AmJSfGhIRGgsFgB3chDUsHx+CC4AYWweSLIABXSwAFsWZXwIAB5cAE9KFgw2OE8nOGgRAG5fVHD0a3ikwPIAImBRwV70PIwQFhCQDH5yYCm0GZw5haWVpj48Mwtm6Bkp7Ty9GkGExNOxmknJA2NTcxZyGkEgA)

Comment: [microsoft/TypeScript#3841](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3841) has more relevant discussion about this; the feature is missing because it's not clear how to add it in any useful or safe way.  What stops someone from writing `class C extends A { constructor(oops: number) { super(oops.toFixed()); } }`?  `new C(123).constructor` is incompatible with `new A("").constructor`, so assuming `a.constructor` is `new (ref: string) => A` is unsafe, and that's why it needs a type assertion

Comment: Sure, thank you `jcalz` for the clear example. My answer assumes OP is knowing what he is doing

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to get `new(ref: string)` out of `A`? I don't want to duplicate its parameter list

Comment: Yes, I think you can do it with `ConstructorParameters<A>`. Updated the answer

Comment: @leonardfactoryt Thank you! How about `const t = a.constructor as typeof A`? I checked and it works. Since it's shorter, I guess it's better?

Comment: Ah you're totally right! I've got lost in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```js
const t = a.constructor as typeof A;
```